# How do current and voltage work in a dipole antenna?

Tags: antenna

I don't know if I understand how it works.

[image]

For example, does it mean that on the right side there is Vmax, for example 5 V, and on the other side there is Vmin = 0 V?

Let's say I have Vin = 5 V.

And how does the current flow here? Because it doesn't look like a capacitor, and the "legs" are very far apart.

Comment: Current is maximum at feedpoint, while voltage is maximum (and opposite sign) at ends. The voltage amplitude at the ends is considerably higher than voltage amplitude at the feedpoint. https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/what-is-the-peak-voltage-at-the-tips-of-a-dipole-antenna

Comment: This link may shed some light: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dipole_receiving_antenna_animation_6_800x394x150ms.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *does it mean that on the right side there is Vmax for example 5V and
> on the other side there is Vmin = 0V ?*

---

<sub>I'll start by saying that to drive a dipole, you need a balanced drive voltage and, that means when one driver line is positive, the other driver line is negative with the same magnitude. Anything else does not correspond with your diagram.</sub>

---

If the balanced signal fed to the antenna is AC and, the peak voltage on one the end of one antenna branch is + 5 volts then, the peak voltage at the end of the other branch is -5 volts.

> *And how does the current flow here ? Because it doesn't look like
> capacitor, and the "legs" are very far apart*

The two opposing antenna branches form an impedance converter from 74 Ω (typical for a dipole) to the impedance of free space (377 Ω) and yes, current does flow and yes, the two branches have capacitance between them as well as self inductance.

> *Let's say I have Vin = 5V*

If Vin is 5 volts RMS, the peak value would be about 7.07 volts. But, along the branches of a resonant dipole, you get voltage magnification (else how could the branches convert typically 74 Ω presented by the electrical terminals to the impedance of free-space (377 Ω).

In other words, you can't apply 5 volts at the electrical terminals and expect to see +/-5 volts at the ends of the antenna branches. You can observe voltage magnification if you look at your picture.

Comment: Isn't it that when I have AC for example AC = 5V. 
Then the potential difference on both side should be equal to 5V right ? 
For example peak voltage is + 5V. So one side has 5V and the other side 0V like here : 

https://tinyurl.com/2qmv2zbx

Comment: No, that is incorrect. A dipole is balanced and, the feed to it also must be balanced.

Comment: How to achieve it with AC source ? As I send in my simulation it like on one side is 5V on the other is 0V. And the potential difference is then 5V. 
In your example if one has 5V and the other has -5V then the voltage difference is 10V. 
Assuming that AC peak is 5V

Comment: Your simulation has 0 volts fixed on one side because that is how you defined it. A balanced source has + on one side and - on the other @user331990. In effect, the midpoint of a balanced voltage source is 0 volts.

Comment: Aha so 0V in this time of this source results in 5V on one side and -5V on the other side ? 
When I have peak which let it be 5V, then I have 5V on one side and 0V on the other side ? And if the peak is -5V then there is again 5V on the other side but 0V on the one side.
And Peak of 0V results in -5V and 5V on both side ?

Comment: No, not at all; 0 volts on one side forces that side to always be 0 volts. Just imagine two voltage sources of 2.5 volts connected in series with the midpoint connection ground. That is a balanced generator.

Comment: Aha so the source in Anthena isn't a typical AC like in my simulation. But it's more of a specific generator ? Like here : https://tinyurl.com/2mvad37o
So 0V should result in 0V on both side. 

Also is the current in phase with the voltage ? 
Because Maximum voltage the current is also maximum but in the pictures it is pretty wierd like it is shifted in phase.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. But, this for a **dipole** antenna and not all antennas. For instance, a **monopole** antenna (half a dipole and much more commonly used aka a whip antenna) would use a single-ended generator as per your earlier link @user331990

Comment: Do you know also why the current is phased ? 
Because for dipole antenna I need a specific generator, but why the current is shifted in phase ?

Comment: This is what happens when the wavelength of the signal generator's output frequency gets close to anything like the length of the antenna. It's quite complex really and involves a lot of math and hair-pulling. I suggest you begin by studying regular RF transmission line theory before moving onto antennas if you want to get to the bottom of this @user331990

Comment: Okey so for now I'll just assume that he current is just shifted.